# PHP doesn't work on Amazon AWS S3 for email contact form

Tags: php, amazon-aws, amazon-s3

I built a website with Adobe Muse, it as HTML, uploaded it to a bucket in Amazon AWS S3, enable webhosting on the bucket, and attached the domain to my website with Amazon Route 53. It can be visited with WWW.Bitframe.tech if needed.

The form at the bottom uses PHP scripts to send a email to me for my customers. When I try to test the form, I get

> Form PHP script is missing from web server, or PHP is not configured correctly on your web hosting provider. Check if the form PHP script has been uploaded correctly, then contact your hosting provider about PHP configuration.

I checked to make sure the PHP files are properly uploaded, and they are.

I'm assuming I have to enable or set something up within Amazon AWS to enable this php script to work? What should I be looking for to solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't S3 just a static file storage service?   If so scripting won't work there and that is why PHP fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 web site hosting is strictly for static content.  Nothing stored in S3 is executable by S3, such as PHP scripts.

This is by design, and not a configuration issue with your site.

> You can host a static website on Amazon S3. On a static website, individual web pages include static content. They may also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. **Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: To add to this, the correct AWS service would be EC2. This would allow you to deploy a virtual web server.